# how to log my program every 10 seconds

Tags: java, file, logging, timer

hi I have a program that prints infinite random texts from server 
in a  while loop and wont stop
, how can I log the data every 10 seconds in a text file ?

```
public class MyServer {
public static String str="";
private volatile boolean running=true;
public synchronized void  socketreceive(){
    try{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(6666);
        Socket s=ss.accept();//establishes connection
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        str=(String)dis.readUTF();


       //this  continuously goes on  and I need to make a log from it
        System.out.println("message= "+str);


        ss.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}

public void receiver(){
 final Thread receive=new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running){
            socketreceive();
    }
    }

});
```

Comment: you would need to start a thread which will sleep for 10 seconds and then write. If you want to be more precise, you would need to define a timer which would wake up your writer thread every 10 sec.

Comment: @Serge I actually need all the data that comes out, i dont see how sleep gets me that.

Comment: So, you have two tasks at hands then: save all the data between dumps and dump it every 10 seconds, cleaning the memory for the next portion. Right? you would need to add some synchronization to allow access to the same memory region from the reader and the writer thread. It might be better to have 2 or more memory regions for this operation, i.e. let the reader fill up a memory region, while the writer writes the previous region, then switch the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of a convenient timer for such a case. The only drawback is that it is a 'swing' timer and it might be a heavy weight one in your case. However it works. I added some skeleton functions for read and write which might provide you with some ideas.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimedLogger {

    List<String>  strings;

    public mySocketReader() {
       ....
       String line = str=(String)dis.readUTF();
       storeLine(line);
       ..
     }

    synchronized void storeLine(String line) {
        strings.add(line);
    }
    synchronized void writeLines() {
       for(String s: strings)
           writeInFile(s);
       strings.clear();
    }

    Timer      timer = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            writeLines();
        }
     });
}
```

So, you reader will save your lines on a list, When there is an interrupt, the writer will write those lines in a file. Since the functions are `synchronized` they cannot be executed at the same time and cannot be executed at the same time and modify the list simultaneously. The only drawback is that you cannot put any new line on the list while the write is going one. Efficiently you cannot read the next line till write is done.

You would need to have 2 (or more lists) and use synchronized function just to change the pointers to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `if-statement` to check for the difference between current time and last logged time, if its `>=` 10sec then start the writer thread. For example:

```
public void run() {
        Date dt = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        while (running){
            Date tmp = new Date();
            if (Integer.parseInt(df.format(tmp)) - Integer.parseInt(df.format(dt)) >= 10)
                // start your writer thread
                dt = tmp
            socketreceive();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how implement a possible solution, in this example the program uses a Queue that store the values that come from multiple socket writters.

```
Queue<String> logValues = new LinkedList<>();
   public synchronized void log(String value) {
    logValues.add(value);
}
```

The Queue is inside a class called `BufferLogger` wich implements a Runnable and wait for 10 seconds to get the current size of the Queue, depending on the size it continue with a for loop that iterates from 0 to queue size and call the poll method from the Queue in order to get the latest element and send the element to the log file, just like a FIFO approach.

```
@Override
public void run() {

    int timeToSave = 10000; //10 seconds
    System.out.printf("Running Program Logger, log files every %d miliseconds. %s%n", timeToSave, new Date().toString());

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(timeToSave);
            this.writeToFile();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void writeToFile() {
    Date date = new Date();
    File myLog = new File(String.format(filename));
    FileWriter myLogWritter = null;
    try {
        myLogWritter = new FileWriter(myLog, true);

        int queueSize = logValues.size();
        myLogWritter.write(String.format("Sending data to log!. Current Log Queue Size: %d.  Time:%s%n", queueSize, date.toString()));
        System.out.printf("Sending data to log!. Current Log Queue Size: %d.  Time:%s.  Filename:%s%n", queueSize, date.toString(), myLog.getName());

        for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++) {
            myLogWritter.write(String.format("%s Logging Value: %s%n", date.toString(), logValues.poll()));
        }

    }
```

I'm sharing the complete code for further information, hope this helps:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Random;


public class ProgramLogger {

    static final int serverPort = 9999;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        BufferLogger bufferLogger = new BufferLogger();
        new Thread(bufferLogger).start();
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            new ClientSender().start(); //client 1
            new ClientSender().start(); //client 2
            new ClientSender().start(); //client 3
            new ClientSender().start(); //client 4
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            new ServerReceptor(socket, bufferLogger).start();
        }
    }

}


class ClientSender extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter out;
    String serverAddress="localhost";
    int serverPort=9999;
    Random randomValue = new Random();

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sarting Client Sender on Thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
            socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            out = out == null ? new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true) : out;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString() + " - " +  randomValue.nextInt(8000));
                Thread.sleep(randomValue.nextInt(800));

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class ServerReceptor extends Thread {
    protected Socket socket;
    private BufferLogger bufferLogger;

    public ServerReceptor(Socket clientSocket, BufferLogger bufferLogger) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
        this.bufferLogger = bufferLogger;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sarting Server Receptor on Thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        String line;
        while (true) {
            try {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    bufferLogger.log(line);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

class BufferLogger implements Runnable {

    Queue<String> logValues = new LinkedList<>();
    Date dateOfCreation = new Date();
    String filename = String.format("myapplog%d.log", dateOfCreation.getTime());

    public synchronized void log(String value) {
        logValues.add(value);
    }

    public void writeToFile() {
        Date date = new Date();
        File myLog = new File(String.format(filename));
        FileWriter myLogWritter = null;
        try {
            myLogWritter = new FileWriter(myLog, true);

            int queueSize = logValues.size();
            myLogWritter.write(String.format("Sending data to log!. Current Log Queue Size: %d.  Time:%s%n", queueSize, date.toString()));
            System.out.printf("Sending data to log!. Current Log Queue Size: %d.  Time:%s.  Filename:%s%n", queueSize, date.toString(), myLog.getName());

            for (int i = 0; i < queueSize; i++) {
                myLogWritter.write(String.format("%s Logging Value: %s%n", date.toString(), logValues.poll()));
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                myLogWritter.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int timeToSave = 10000; //10 seconds
        System.out.printf("Running Program Logger, log files every %d miliseconds. %s%n", timeToSave, new Date().toString());

        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(timeToSave);
                this.writeToFile();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```